# Multiple languages in Sql Server databases - what are the implications?

Tags: sql-server

I've read the related answers but they don't answer my question directly, and I am a little unclear on the details of localisation, and I'm not sure exactly where any language 'conversion' takes place.

I have a C# application and Sql Server (2008 onwards) database which is all in English. A new requirement is to supply this product to an Arabic customer, such that the data entered and viewed is all in Arabic.

1. Is this possible without changing all the SQL and the stored procedures in the application?
2. Is it possible for multiple clients (English and Arabic, say) to store data in the database in different languages (we are talkng English using the Latin alphabet, and Arabic using an Arabic alphabet, and using the same tables)?
3. If the database is set to a collation that supports Arabic, will the table names and column names remain in 'English'? ie, will the SQL remain 'English' SQL even though the client application is running on an 'Arabic' Windows machine?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: yes, unless the original developer thought the world is english and used Char / Carchar fields instead of NChar / NVarchar. Happens.

2: Yes, as I said - SQL Server can deal with unicode.

3: Structure is irrelevant. The SQL does not magically change. STandard is to have one (english) schema and only rename the content. In general SQL Server will not rename objects when you install the database on a machine in another language.

Comment: Q2 expanded: Can multiple languages/alphabets be stored in the same row? Can I store something in both English and Arabic side by side?

Comment: Which poart of "unicode" is not clear? Maybe some basic research on waht Unicode is would be better?

Comment: @NeilHaughton Unicode is essentially a single encoding method which encompasses any characters in almost all known written languages. It is essentially unaware of language at all; there are just a bunch of encodings. There are multiple flavors, but my point applies anyway, and it should be stated that this is a gross oversimplification.